# Add Search filed in App Bar with Navigation Drawer flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am newbie into flutter. I have created a `Navigation Drawer` and it has multiple selection. In each seletion of drawer i have screen which consists of `List` of Data coming from `server`.

Now i want add `Search Icon` to `Navigation Bar` with `Editfield` to filter the list detials and update on the screen of any selected item from `Navigation Drawer`.

Please help me out.. and will be appreciated.

**NavigationDrawer Screen**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/AnnouncementsScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/AttendeesScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/BookmarksScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/ExibitorsScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/HomeScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/InnovationsScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/MeetingsScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/PrivacyPolicyScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/ProgramScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/SpeedSessionScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/fragments/TermsConditionsScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/utils/Utils.dart';

class HomeDashboard extends StatefulWidget {

  final drawerItems = [
    new DrawerItem("Dashboard"),
    new DrawerItem("Program"),
    new DrawerItem("Exibitors"),
    new DrawerItem("Innovations"),
    new DrawerItem("Attendees"),
    new DrawerItem("Speed Session"),
    new DrawerItem("Bookmarks"),
    new DrawerItem("Announcements"),
    new DrawerItem("Privacy Policy"),
    new DrawerItem("Terms & Conditions"),
    new DrawerItem("Logout")
  ];

  @override
  _HomeDashboardState createState() => _HomeDashboardState();
}

class _HomeDashboardState extends State<HomeDashboard> {

  int _selectedDrawerIndex = 0;

  //Let's use a switch statement to return the Fragment for a selected item
  _getDrawerFragment(int pos) {
    switch (pos) {
      case 0:
        return new HomeScreen();
      case 1:
        return new ProgramScreen();
      case 2:
        return new ExibitorsScreen();
      case 3:
        return new InnovationsScreen();
      case 4:
        return new AttendeesScreen();
      case 5:
        return new SpeedSessionScreen();
      case 6:
        return new BookmarksScreen();
      case 7:
        return new AnnouncementsScreen();
      case 8:
        return new PrivacyPolicyScreen();
      case 9:
        return new TermsConditionsScreen();

      default:
        return new Text("Error");
    }
  }
  //Let's update the selectedDrawerItemIndex the close the drawer
  _onSelectItem(int index) {
    setState(() => _selectedDrawerIndex = index);
    //we close the drawer
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> drawerOptions = [];
    //Let's create drawer list items. Each will have an icon and text
    for (var i = 0; i < widget.drawerItems.length; i++) {
      var d = widget.drawerItems[i];
      drawerOptions.add(
          ListTile(
            title: new Text(d.title),
            selected: i == _selectedDrawerIndex,
            onTap: () => _onSelectItem(i),
          )
      );
    }
    //Let's scaffold our homepage
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        // We will dynamically display title of selected page
        title: new Text(widget.drawerItems[_selectedDrawerIndex].title),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Search',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: (){

            },
          ),

          IconButton(
            tooltip: 'Search',
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list),
            onPressed: (){

            },
          )
        ],
      ),
      // Let's register our Drawer to the Scaffold
      drawer: SafeArea(
        child: new Drawer(
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                color: Utils.hexToColor("#F24A1C"),
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 10,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text('Menu', style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white
                      ))
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Column(children: drawerOptions)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: _getDrawerFragment(_selectedDrawerIndex),
    );
  }
}

//Let's define a DrawerItem data object
class DrawerItem {
  String title;
  IconData icon;
  DrawerItem(this.title);
}
```

Here, in `NavigationDrawer Screen`, onclick of search icon `TextField` should enable and in `List Screen` filter should happen when user starting typing.

**List Screen**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:innovation_bridge/detailScreens/ProgramDetailScreen.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/dialogs/CommonMessageDialog.dart';
import 'package:innovation_bridge/utils/Utils.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';

class ProgramScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProgramScreenState createState() => _ProgramScreenState();
}

class _ProgramScreenState extends State<ProgramScreen> {

  var meteors = [
    "Tunguska",
    "Crab Pulsar",
    "Geminga",
    "Calvera",
    "Vela X-1",
  ];

  final String uri = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';

  Future<List<Users>> _fetchUsers() async {
    print('@@ inside fetch user == ');
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(uri));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
      List<Users> listOfUsers = items.map<Users>((json) {
        return Users.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfUsers;
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load internet');
    }
  }

  CalendarController _calendarController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('@@ CALLBACK: _onDaySelected' +day.toIso8601String());
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            color: Colors.grey[350],
            child: _buildTableCalendar(),
          ),

          Expanded(
            child:  StreamBuilder(
              stream: Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ConnectivityResult> snapShot){
                if (!snapShot.hasData) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                var result = snapShot.data;
                switch (result) {
                  case ConnectivityResult.none:
                    print("no net");
                    return Center(child: Text("No Internet Connection! none "));
                  case ConnectivityResult.mobile:
                    return _listDetials();
                  case ConnectivityResult.wifi:
                    print("yes net");
                    return _listDetials();
                  default:
                    return Center(child: Text("No Internet Connection! default"));
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  FutureBuilder _listDetials(){
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _fetchUsers(),
      builder: (context, snapshot){
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        }
        else{
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 5,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index){
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 10.0, 15.0, 4),
                child: Container(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => ProgramDetailScreen()
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Text('Program Activity Title', style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 18,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400
                        )),
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6)),
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Text('Location Name', style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                            )),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 2,
                            child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: Text('Start time - End time', style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                ))
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 6)),
                      Text('Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),),
                      ExpansionTile(
                        title: Text(''),
                        trailing: Icon(
                          Icons.face,
                          size: 36.0,
                        ),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GridView.count(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                              crossAxisCount: 3,
                              crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                              mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                              childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                  (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: (){

                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          width: 0.9
                                      ),
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(5.0) //                 <--- border radius here
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 5, 0, 0),
                                          child: Text('Session Title',
                                              softWrap: true,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 10,
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 1, 0, 0),
                                          child:  Text('10:00 - 10:30',
                                              softWrap: true,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 9
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(6, 1, 0, 0),
                                          child: Text('Hall B',
                                              softWrap: true,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontSize: 9
                                              )),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                              ]),
                        ],
                        // onExpansionChanged: (bool expanding) => setState(() => this.isExpanded = expanding),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

  // Simple TableCalendar configuration (using Styles)
  Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
    return TableCalendar(
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.monday,
      headerVisible: true,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.week, availableCalendarFormats: const { CalendarFormat.week: 'Week', },
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
          selectedColor: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          todayColor: Colors.deepOrange[200],
          markersColor: Colors.brown[700],
          outsideDaysVisible: true
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.deepOrange[400],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      onDaySelected: _onDaySelected,
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }
}



Widget createGridView(BuildContext context, List<String> cosmicBodies) {
  //I will shuffle my data
  cosmicBodies.shuffle();

  // Then build my GridView and return it
  return new GridView.builder(
      itemCount: cosmicBodies.length,
      gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3, mainAxisSpacing: 15.0),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return new GestureDetector(
          child: new Card(
            elevation: 5.0,
            child: new Container(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              margin: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 10.0),
              child: new Text(cosmicBodies[index]),
            ),
          ),
        );
      });
}

class Users {
  int id;
  String name;
  String username;
  String email;

  Users({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.username,
    this.email,
  });

  factory Users.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Users(
      id: json['id'],
      name: json['name'],
      email: json['email'],
      username: json['username'],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What you have tried so far?
Please show some code.

Comment: I have just added the `search icon` in `Navigation Bar` Okay i will add the code

Comment: @ibhavikmakwana, i have updated the code, please help me

Comment: @MohammedZaheer Have you find Solution for how to access search icon from Navigation item screen?
I am facing same issue can you please help me?

Comment: @AndroidPlayer - Yes i have figured out the solution

Comment: @AndroidPlayer - Have you added the search Icon in `AppBar`. OnPress of icon you have to show the `TextField` and replace the serch Icon with close Icon.

Let me know you required much on this.

Comment: @MohammedZaheer - Yes i added Search Icon in App Bar and show icon when My Survey Fragment is Loaded from `_getDrawerFragment()` but i need to filter My Survey Fragment when i write something in Search TextField from appBar. Can i manage Searchbar from Survey Fragment?

Comment: @AndroidPlayer - Yes, you can manage and also can pass entered text to your Survey Class. Use `final GlobalKey<_SurveyScreenState> _key = GlobalKey();`
_key.currentState.methodUpdateFilter(controller.text);

SurveyScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);
Add this `methodUpdateFilter` in your Survey Class

Comment: @AndroidPlayer - In SurveyClass add a constructor to get the `GlobalKey` reference

SurveyScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

Comment: @MohammedZaheer - How can i access `methodUpdateFilter` in HomeScreen? If you can give me example code, it would be very helpful me, because i am new to flutter.

Comment: @AndroidPlayer -  In `HomeScreen` i guess u have `AppBar`. So in `SurveyScreen` u define the method `methodUpdateFilter` with parameter String.

Comment: @MohammedZaheer - Thank you, man! I really appreciate your help :)